# How do you reconnect when there's a failure in the stream?

Tags: java, spring

I have a code that looks like this

```
@PostConstruct
public void setUpStreamer() {
    WebClient.create(daemonEndpoint)
        .get()
        .uri("/events)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(String.class)
        .flatMap(Mono::justOrEmpty)
        .map(s -> {
            try {
                return mapper.readValue(s, Map.class);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.warn("unable to parse {} as JSON", s);
                return null;
            }
        })
        .flatMap(Mono::justOrEmpty)
        .subscribe(
            events -> {
                log.info("service event(s) detected");
            },
            throwable -> log.error("Error on event stream: {}", throwable.getMessage(), throwable),
            () -> log.warn("event stream completed")
        );
}
```

What I want to do is on failure of the stream, basically the event endpoint decides to disconnect or restart, that the streamer will be recreated again.

Something like this

```
            throwable -> {
                log.error("Error on event stream: {}", throwable.getMessage(), throwable);
                setUpStreamer();
            },
            () -> {
                log.warn("event stream completed");
                setUpStreamer();
            }
```

Is that the only way to do that or is there some nicer annotation or operator that would do the work for me?